# PHP: Create Mongo database

Tags: php, mongodb, database-backups

At following line i'm trying to create mongo database backup at specified path but it's not working. let me know what's wrong. Thank you.

```
 $command = "mongodump --db test --dbpath D:/dump/db";
     $results = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"it's not working"_?

Answer (score 0):

Note:

```
     shell_exec($command); does not work for windows!
```

It does not return result or might it returns some error. shell_exec work only for linux based systems like ubuntu.

if you still have some issues just hit mongodump command directly over your command prompt.

Comment: I want to create backup of mongodb database in php

Comment: @Shabeer which type of system you are using is it linux based or windows based? so that i can help you accordingly.